# Module not found even though explicitly added to system path

Tags: python, path, sys

I am trying to use Lumerical in python. Lumerical is an electromagnetic simulation software that allows access via python. For more information, please refer to https://support.lumerical.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041873053

Anyway, to make it run, I need to import a module called `lumapi`. It's located in the program's directory:

`C:\Program Files\Lumerical\v202\api\python\lumapi.py`

So, naturally, to import it into my current script file, I used the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Lumerical\v202\api\python\lumapi.py")

import lumapi
```

But I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lumapi'
```

**What I have tested**

1. When I save the script file directly inside the folder where
   `lumapi` is stored and just write `import lumapi` it works.
2. With `sys.path` I have tested if the directory was indeed added to
   the path, and it seems to be the case
3. I also made sure that I have full write and read permission to the
   folder where lumapi is stored

Comment: `sys.path` should have _directory names_, not python script file names, in it.

Comment: @martineau Thank you so much. I did not know that, but f course it makes sense! This answers my question. :) Maybe you can add it as an answer that I can accept.

Comment: henry: Thanks for the offer. No worries — easy mistake to make, IMO.